# How do I get tf.exe to set the Source Control Folder to something other than the root?

Tags: tfs

So I am trying to script with TFS using the `tf.exe` command.  I've looked at the docs but I can't seem to determine how to set the server path such that I don't get the intermediate path in my local directory.

E.g. The server has a dir that I want to get called `$/Some/Depth/TargetDir` and I want to put it in `C:\MyFolder\StoreHere` such that all files in `TargetDir` and all directories beneath it are stored in `StoreHere`.

Currently, I'm using `tf get $/Some/Depth/TargetDir /recursive` which results in the files in `TargetDir` to be downloaded, but in to `C:\MyFolder\Storehere\Some\Depth\TargetDir` which is not what I want.

I'm using TFS 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Workspace mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control where server paths are retrieved to your local paths.  In the behavior you describe, you have a workspace mapping that resolves `$/Some/Depth/TargetDir` to `C:\MyFolder\Storehere\Some\Depth\TargetDir`.

Not having seen your actual workspace mappings, it's impossible for me to know exactly why, but this could be as simple as having a workspace mapping from `$/` to `C:\MyFolder\Storehere`.

Instead, you need to map the actual directory you're interested in:  you need a mapping from `$/Some/Depth/TargetDir` to `C:\MyFolder\Storehere`.

You will need to delete the existing, incorrect mapping first.

You could set this up in the Visual Studio [Edit Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245466%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) dialog, or you could use the [command-line client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
tf workfold /unmap C:\MyFolder\Storehere
tf workfold /map $/Some/Depth/TargetDir C:\MyFolder\Storehere
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  This is part of a batch file so I don't actually have to unmap as I could map prior to getting the files which works marvellously.  :)